# Getting Windows Security Error "0x8009035D" with SHA-1 certificate

Tags: windows, sockets, security, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am using net socket programming at client side for connecting to the server. When the server is sending SHA-256 signed certificate I am not getting any error, communication is taking place smoothly.

In my personal PC SHA-1 signed certificate is also working fine. But when SHA-1 certificates are deployed in production environment, I am getting error "0x8009035D" at the client side:

> "InitializeSecurityContext returned '2148074333"

Assume that server simple windows TCP/TLS based server. Its looks to me this is due to the client rejecting SHA-1 certificate.

Is there any way to reproduce the issue in my PC by modifying registry or workaround? I can't share code but I am sure it's working as expected, the problem lies with client OS setting problem or with the host.